# Force login to Yammer without displaying the popup window

Tags: yammer

We are currently developing a yammer custom widget for one of our clients. This widget interacts with data from a Yammer External Network since we require users from other Yammer networks to be able to access it.

The only way we have managed to make it work is through the use of JS SDK.

yam.platform.login(function (data) { console.log(data) })
yam.platform.getLoginStatus(function (data) { console.log(data) })

We noticed that it creates a hidden iframe that servers as proxy to overcome cross domain issues. However, every time we refresh the browser, we lose the token and the iframe must authenticate again.

- Would deploying the app to the global catalog prevent the sdk from needing to go for the iframe approach? (It seems won't do the trick)
- Otherwise, is there a known way to modify the popup parameter?

many thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer, it is just a matter of manually setting the previously obtained token:

Logging in the first time to obtain the token:

```
yam.platform.login({ network: '{your-permalink-goes-here}' }
```

and then if the page is reloaded

```
yam.platform.setAuthToken('{the-token-goes-here}'))
```